# Evaluating $\sum_{k = 1}^{89} \cot (k^\circ)$

Tags: trigonometry

I have found a sum I do not know how to evaluate. $$\sum_{k = 1}^{89} \cot (k^\circ)$$
I think I should multiply it with another trigonometric function, but I do not know which one.

Comment: $\cot 0 $ is undefined

Comment: My bad, I am a little tired.

Comment: Just asking, are you sure it is the sum of cotangents? Because, if it were the product $\cot1^{\circ}\cdots\cot89^\circ$, the answer is $1$

Comment: I am quite sure. Why is it 1?

Comment: $\cot x= \tan (90^\circ-x)$

Comment: In my opinion, it must be the product and not the sum.

Answer (score 2):

Some progress:

Let the argument of $\cot$ and $\tan$ functions be in degrees
$$S=\sum_{1}^{89} \cot k~~~~~~~(1)$$
$$\implies S=\sum_{k=1}^{89} \cot (90-k) ~~~~~(2)$$
Adding (1) and (2) we get
$$2S=\sum_{k=1}^{89} [\cot k + \tan k] =\sum_{k=1}^{89} \frac{2}{\sin 2k}$$
$$\implies S=\sum_{k=1}^{89} \csc 2x, $$
This sum is finite but not doable in terms of simple functions.